# Insert to Sqlite DataBase in isolated storage performance

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-store-apps

In My Windows Strore App I have SQLite DataBase in Isolated Storage.
I use [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) library.
For save data to DataBase i use follow:

```
 public static async Task Save<T>(List<T> items) 
    {
        var serverFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("FolgerName");
        var storageFile = await serverFolder.GetFileAsync("DataBaseName.sqlite");
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(storageFile.Path))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Save to DataBase " + (typeof(T)) + " started " + DateTime.Now.Minute + ":" + DateTime.Now.Second + ":" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            try 
            {
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    db.InsertOrReplace(item);
                }
                Debug.WriteLine("Save to DataBase " + (typeof(T)) + " success " + DateTime.Now.Minute + ":" + DateTime.Now.Second + ":" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            }
            catch
            (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Save to DataBase " + (typeof(T)) + " error. Result: " + ex.Result + "  Message: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have question about performance:
1226 objects with 60 fields in each saved in DataBase in 4 and half MINUTES!
 
It's normal?
How I can make it faster?

**Update**

When I use:

```
  public static async Task Save<T>(List<T> items, Server server) where T : IHasId
    {
        var serverFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync(server.FolgerName);
        var storageFile = await serverFolder.GetFileAsync("kaliti.sqlite");
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(storageFile.Path))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Save to DataBase " + (typeof(T)) + " started" + String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now));
            try
            {
                var table = db.Table<T>();
                var idList = new List<int>();
                foreach (var i in table)
                {
                    idList.Add(i.Id);
                }
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    if (idList.Contains(item.Id))
                        {
                            db.Delete<T>(item.Id);
                        }
                    db.Insert(item);
                }
                Debug.WriteLine("Save to DataBase " + (typeof(T)) + " success" + String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now));
            }
            catch
            (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Save to DataBase " + (typeof(T)) + " error. Result: " + ex.Result + "  Message: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

and DataBase is empty I have the same stuff.

Comment: The code for InsertOrReplace is critical here

Comment: ok, but when DataBase is Empty and I use only Insert - i have the same stuff!((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run as many database calls as possible inside of a transaction. Doing this speeds things up greatly.  Here is a sample transaction, using code from your first example:

```
...
try 
{
    db.RunInTransaction(() =>
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            db.InsertOrReplace(item);
        }
    });
...
```

Comment: elegant way. thanks. instead of 4 and half minute, now I have couple seconds.